# How to make a dynamic roles guard, to work in both controllers and handlers

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

I'm defining a roles guard like this:

```js
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private reflector: Reflector,
  ) { }

  async matchRoles(roles: string[], userRole: User["roles"]) {
    let match = false;

    if (roles.indexOf(userRole) > -1) {
      match = true;
    }

    return match
  }

  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getClass());
    if (!roles) {
      return true;
    }
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user: User = request.user;

    return this.matchRoles(roles, user.roles)
  }
}
```

in this roles example it works only in a controller level like this:

```js
@Controller('games')
@hasRoles('user')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard(), JwtGuard, RolesGuard)
export class GamesController {
...
```

But i want it to work dynamically with both, at controller level, and handler level.
so i can appy a `@hasRoles('user')` for every route in the controller, and `@hasRoles('admin')` for some routes  in that controller.

So to do this i need to change the reflector method from `getClass` to `getHandler` dynamically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nest's `Reflector` has a built-in method to merge the metadata set on controllers and route handlers with `getAllAndMerge` which will merge the metadata from the class and the method. To use it you would do something like

```js
const roles = this.reflector.getAllAndMerge(
  'roles',
  [
    context.getHandler(),
    context.getClass()
  ]
);
```

If you wanted to get just one set of metadata and have a fallback (say if you want only the handler metadata if it exists and if not get the class's metadata) you can use `getAllAndOverride` in a similar manner

```js
const roles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride(
  'roles',
  [
    context.getHandler(),
    context.getClass()
  ]
);
```

[You can read more in-depth about it here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#reflection-and-metadata).